# Modify and Read Global variable after session in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to read a global variable which is declared before UI. In a scenario I am modifying the global variable during the session and in observer function. But when I want to print that modified variable after session kill, it prints old values itself. I want to keep this modified variable(in my requirement every time it changes on each session) for each session.

```
library(shiny)    

timeoutSeconds <- 5
varA <- 3 #Declaring Global variable    

#Trigger the function after the 5 seconds 
inactivity <- sprintf("
function idleTimer() {
var t = setTimeout(logout, %s);
window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

function logout() {
   Shiny.setInputValue('timeOut', '%ss')
  }

function resetTimer() {
   clearTimeout(t);
   t = setTimeout(logout, %s);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
   }
}
idleTimer();", 
timeoutSeconds*1000, 
timeoutSeconds, 
timeoutSeconds*1000)

#UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(inactivity)  

)

#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){


  observeEvent(input$timeOut, {
    varA <-varA + 1 #Modifing this global variable for each session

    print(paste0("Session (", session$token, ") timed out at: ", Sys.time()))
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Timeout",
      paste("Session timeout due to", input$timeOut, "inactivity -", Sys.time()),
      footer = NULL
    ))
    session$close()
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {

    #Should print 4
    print(varA) #Printing the modified  variable  during sessions

  })

})

runApp(ui,server)
```

I want to print 4 in the above code. I have tried multiple times, but  may be it doesn't work like that. can you please help me anyone on this.

Answer (score 0):

`print(varA)` is outside the `observeEvent` function so it will print the initial value of `varA` (which is 3) and not the updated value (4). The solution is to put `print(varA)` just below `session$close()` in the `observeEvent` function.

That means you can remove the (now empty)  `session$onSessionEnded(function() { })` function.

Comment: in my case, I need to capture the variable after session is ended

Comment: well then I don't understand, do you want to print 4 every time ? or 4 the first time and then 5, 6... ?

Comment: as of now, please help me to print 4 (which is modified in observeevent)

Comment: the answer I provided prints 4 in the console when the session is ended

Comment: is there any other possibilities to print 4 in onsessionend function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`varA <<-varA + 1`

To change the global variable

Comment: I think it will change for all the users.. this change is not session specific

Comment: can we maintain userid in such variables as user id will unique for each user.